# Procedure in if loop not working even though condition is met

Tags: python, if-statement

I have made this code to emulate a rock paper scissors game. I have a procedure which has the main game, and when I run this by itself without the if loop at the end, it works. However, when I try to validate whether or not the user entry is numerical, it does not print the correct message. Here is the full code:

```
import random
def game(choice):
    number = random.randint(1,3)
    if choice == 1 and number == 2:
        print("You lose.")
    if choice == 1 and number ==3:
        print("You win.")
    if choice == 1 and number == 1:
        print("It is a draw")
    if choice == 2 and number == 3:
        print("You lose.")
    if choice == 2 and number ==1:
        print("You win.")
    if choice == 2 and number == 2:
        print("It is a draw")
    if choice == 3 and number == 1:
        print("You lose.")
    if choice == 3 and number ==2:
        print("You win.")
    if choice == 3 and number == 3:
        print("It is a draw")  
x = input("Choose 1 (rock), 2 (paper) or 3 (scissors).")
digit = x.isdigit()
if digit == True:
    game(x)
```

By the way, there is no error message, the procedure just does not work!

Comment: Your input `x` is a string, not  a number. You have to convert it into an integer with `int()`.

Comment: @Piinthesky is right. You should probably use "elif" rather than a ton of if statements, and include and "else" at the end to print something if none of the conditions are met.

Comment: also you can use `if number == choice` for a draw to condense it slightly

Comment: You could also do `if choice == number: print("It is a draw."); elif number == (choice + 1) % 3: print("You lose."); else: print("You win.")`

Comment: There's no such thing as an if-loop for one thing...

Comment: @mypetlion True...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are a few issues with your code. If you wish to ignore, skip to *Error Handling* for answer to your question. You will find it in there.

### Naming Variables

Your variables do not tell a person reading your code what they are. If you showed someone the word `number`, they would not know that it is what the computer chooses in rock paper scissors. Same with `choice` (who's choice?) and even more so `x`. So why don't we name them `computer_choice`, `user_choice` and `choice` respectively. I know these are a bit longer to type, but it is worth sacrificing a few extra keystrokes for a bit more clarity. Also notice that I used `snake_case` name formatting as per usual Python standards.

### Repetitiveness/ `game()`

Your `game` function could do with a bit of re-doing. All you need is a general 'formula' for winning and losing. In this case, losing is when (thanks to @Brett Beatty) `if computer_choice == (user_choice + 1) % 3`, drawing is when `computer_choice == user_choice` and winning is everything `else`. Also, when your code is being played, the user only knows if they have won or lost, and not what the computer chose, so to add a bit more clarity, I added a list and another `print()` line. This feature is also useful to test code. Additionally, use zero-based variable values, such as in the `computer_choice` and `user_choice` variables. This is useful when converting values to list indexes. Below is a revised version of your code that i have made which includes all points above (I have also made it a function, as you will see below - I just think it looks better):

```
import random


def game(user_choice):
    user_choice -= 1
    rps = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    computer_choice = random.randint(0, 2)
    print("You: {} Computer: {}".format(rps[user_choice], rps[computer_choice]))
    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        return 0
    elif computer_choice == (user_choice + 1) % 3:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1
```

### Error Handling

**To make sure the user enters an integer, you would have to add `int()` around the input statement**. However, this alone would return `ValueError` if the value entered by the user is not an integer, and this is a problem. However, there is a way to fix this using `try: except: else:` blocks, as you will see below. This is what you would need to decide if the value is an integer, it also prints the correct message when it is not. I also think this is what you wanted for `if digit == True`(FYI you would only need `if digit` if you were to do it that way).

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input("Choose 1 (rock), 2 (paper) or 3 (scissors):"))
        except ValueError: # If any part of the code in the try block raises a ValueError
            print("Not an integer")
        else:  # If error is not raised
            if not 1 <= value <= 3: # If value is not between 1 and 3
                print("Must be between 1 and 3")
            else:
                result = game(value) # sets result to return value from game()
                break
    if result == 1:
        print("You Win")
    elif result == -1:
        print("You Lose")
    else:
        print("It's a Draw")
```

### And Finally, the '`if loop`'?

Let me just make this clear. There is no such thing as an `if loop`!!! An `if` statement runs code ****ONCE**** if a certain condition is `True`. I think what you want is a `while` loop. This runs code ****REPEATEDLY**** as long as a certain condition is True. In the code below, I created a `while True` loop, which runs the code each time the user types in `"y"`, and `break`s from the loop if not.
Also, use `if __name__ == '__main__'`. It exists in Python so that Python files can act as either reusable modules, or as standalone programs. It also looks more complex, if you want to look smart.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
        if input("Again? Yes(y) No(Anything else): ").lower() != 'y':
            break
```

Example Output (ignore colours):

```
Choose 1 (rock), 2 (paper) or 3 (scissors):1
You: Rock Computer: Scissors
You Win
Again? Yes(y) No(Anything else): y
Choose 1 (rock), 2 (paper) or 3 (scissors):3
You: Scissors Computer: Scissors
It's a Draw
Again? Yes(y) No(Anything else): y
Choose 1 (rock), 2 (paper) or 3 (scissors):2
You: Paper Computer: Paper
It's a Draw
Again? Yes(y) No(Anything else): n

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Also, for the OP, if you haven't already, I would recommend downloading [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). It is completely free, and makes coding a lot easier. It also improves presentation too. It picks up on some of the things mentioned above, as well as keeping your code in line with PEP guidelines.

Comment: Nice review, but it doesn't explain the actual problem.

Comment: Wasn't the actual problem looping it?

Comment: Oh wait. It was deciding whether the input was numerical. I covered that in the Error Handling section

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701246/procedure-in-if-loop-not-working-even-though-condition-is-met/47702588?noredirect=1#comment82362463_47701246) to the question.

Comment: Ok. Will add to answer

Comment: In Error Handling section